# Modify main window while tkinter button is unpressed

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

I am trying to create a canvas that the user can draw rectangles on  and once they are finished press the "Finished" button to move on to the next segment of the program.

I tried creating a while loop in my create_obstacles function, but this creates the button box that is unclickable and a main canvas that is uneditable.

I'm trying to avoid this linear process that I keep running into with tkinter code examples. Any help would be appreciated!

```
class ExampleApp(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self)
        self.x = self.y = 0
        self.canvas = tk.Canvas(self, width=512, height=512, cursor="cross")
        self.canvas.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)  

    def create_obstacles(self):
        root = tk.Tk()
        root.geometry('100x50')
        btn = Button(root, text ="Click when finished drawing obstacles",command = root.destroy,state="disabled")
        btn.pack()
        root.mainloop()
        while root:

            self.canvas.bind("<ButtonPress-1>", self.on_button_press)
            self.canvas.bind("<B1-Motion>", self.on_move_press)
            self.canvas.bind("<ButtonRelease-1>", self.on_button_release)
            self.rect = None
            self.start_x = None
            self.start_y = None

    def on_button_press(self, event):
        # save mouse drag start position
        self.start_x = event.x
        self.start_y = event.y

        # create rectangle 
        self.rect = self.canvas.create_rectangle(self.x, self.y, 1, 1, fill="black")

    def on_move_press(self, event):
        curX, curY = (event.x, event.y)

        # expand rectangle as you drag the mouse
        self.canvas.coords(self.rect, self.start_x, self.start_y, curX, curY)

    def on_button_release(self, event):
        pass


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = ExampleApp()
    app.create_obstacles()
    app.create_starting_point()
    app.mainloop()
```

Comment: Do not use while loops and do not use multiple mainloops in Tkinter programs. You run mainloop ONCE to start processing system events. If you stop processing events (ie you run a tight loop) then the UI freezes. Instead, you *bind* functions to response to events and use the `after` method or `event_generate` to raise custom events or schedule a task for some time later. If you have a lot of work to do, use after to call the worker repeatedly until the work is complete. Each time, do a small part of the work.

Comment: Thanks for the information! So to do the desired action (Open a dialogue box that says "draw rectangles on the main canvas. Press Okay when done" once they finished drawing rectangles, pressing okay on the dialogue box will then close the dialogue box leaving only main canvas with rectangles) would I need to bind a function which closes the dialogue box to the button?  I'm not sure why but it seems like opening a new dialogue box or button will make the main canvas un-editable.